# Discord Bot on Heroku not online

Tags: heroku, discord, bots

Hello everyone I have looked up this issue but can't find an answer to my specific problem.

So basically the bot is not turning on, it is offline. I don't know where to put the token or how to put the token. Please let me know of the problem or if you need more code/details. Thank you.

Code URL: https://github.com/Verggz/Electrolite

main.bot.js

```
"use strict";
var __awaiter = (this && this.__awaiter) || function (thisArg, _arguments, P, generator) {
        function adopt(value) { return value instanceof P ? value : new P(function (resolve) { resolve(value); }); }
        return new (P || (P = Promise))(function (resolve, reject) {
            function fulfilled(value) { try { step(generator.next(value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
            function rejected(value) { try { step(generator["throw"](value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
            function step(result) { result.done ? resolve(result.value) : adopt(result.value).then(fulfilled, rejected); }
            step((generator = generator.apply(thisArg, _arguments || [])).next());
        });
    };
    var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
        return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
    };
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    const discord_js_1 = __importDefault(require("discord.js"));
    const builders_1 = require("@discordjs/builders");
    const SlashCommand_model_1 = require("./model/SlashCommand.model");
    const HelpCommand_command_1 = require("./commands/HelpCommand.command");
    const fs_extra_1 = __importDefault(require("fs-extra"));
    const BINFlipCommand_command_1 = require("./commands/flip/BINFlipCommand.command");
    var client = new discord_js_1.default.Client({ "intents": [discord_js_1.default.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, discord_js_1.default.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS, discord_js_1.default.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
    client.on('ready', () => __awaiter(void 0, void 0, void 0, function* () {
        var helpcommandbuilder = new builders_1.SlashCommandBuilder()
            .setName("help")
            .setDescription("Get the list of commands that Project: Scyll has.");
        var binflipcommandbuilder = new builders_1.SlashCommandBuilder()
            .setName("binflip")
            .setDescription("Finds a BIN snipe on the auction house based on the amount of profit you can make.")
            .addIntegerOption(option => option.setName("profit")
            .setDescription("the amount of profit you would like to make.").setRequired(true));
        SlashCommand_model_1.SlashCommand.CreateSlashCommands([helpcommandbuilder, binflipcommandbuilder]);
    }));
    client.on('interactionCreate', function (interaction) {
        return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () {
            if (!interaction.isCommand())
                return;
            new HelpCommand_command_1.HelpCommand(interaction);
            new BINFlipCommand_command_1.BINFlipCommand(interaction);
        });
    });
    client.login(fs_extra_1.default.readJSONSync("./config.json").SERVER_BOT_KEY);
```

Another file:

```
"use strict";
var __createBinding = (this && this.__createBinding) || (Object.create ? (function(o, m, k, k2) {
    if (k2 === undefined) k2 = k;
    Object.defineProperty(o, k2, { enumerable: true, get: function() { return m[k]; } });
}) : (function(o, m, k, k2) {
    if (k2 === undefined) k2 = k;
    o[k2] = m[k];
}));
var __setModuleDefault = (this && this.__setModuleDefault) || (Object.create ? (function(o, v) {
    Object.defineProperty(o, "default", { enumerable: true, value: v });
}) : function(o, v) {
    o["default"] = v;
});
var __importStar = (this && this.__importStar) || function (mod) {
    if (mod && mod.__esModule) return mod;
    var result = {};
    if (mod != null) for (var k in mod) if (k !== "default" && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(mod, k)) __createBinding(result, mod, k);
    __setModuleDefault(result, mod);
    return result;
};
var __awaiter = (this && this.__awaiter) || function (thisArg, _arguments, P, generator) {
    function adopt(value) { return value instanceof P ? value : new P(function (resolve) { resolve(value); }); }
    return new (P || (P = Promise))(function (resolve, reject) {
        function fulfilled(value) { try { step(generator.next(value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function rejected(value) { try { step(generator["throw"](value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function step(result) { result.done ? resolve(result.value) : adopt(result.value).then(fulfilled, rejected); }
        step((generator = generator.apply(thisArg, _arguments || [])).next());
    });
};
var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.SlashCommand = void 0;
const discord_js_1 = require("discord.js");
const axios = __importStar(require("axios"));
const rest_1 = require("@discordjs/rest");
const v9_1 = require("discord-api-types/v9");
const fs_extra_1 = __importDefault(require("fs-extra"));
var token = fs_extra_1.default.readJSONSync("./config.json").SERVER_BOT_KEY;
class SlashCommand {
    constructor(interaction) {
        this.http = axios.default;
        this.interaction = interaction;
        this.command = interaction.commandName;
        this.purple = "#BA55D3";
        this.backtick = "`";
        this.gold = "#d4af37";
        this.red = "#C70039";
    }
    CreateEmbed() {
        return new discord_js_1.MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor("Project: Scyll", this.interaction.client.user.avatarURL()).setFooter("Project:Scyll 0.1.0").setTimestamp();
    }
    static CreateSlashCommands(commands) {
        return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () {
            var clientid = (yield fs_extra_1.default.readJSON("./config.json")).SERVER_CLIENT_ID;
            yield SlashCommand.REST.put(v9_1.Routes.applicationCommands(clientid), { "body": commands });
        });
    }
}
exports.SlashCommand = SlashCommand;
SlashCommand.REST = new rest_1.REST({ "version": "9" }).setToken(token);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for a config.json file and put you token there

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).